# Как вращать элементы в Qt Designer без кода или функции rotate

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcreator

Нужно повернуть на несколько градусов label посредством Qt Designer. Не предлагайте реализовать кодом или функцией rotate. Я не конвертирую ui в py и не хочу юзать костыли.

Comment: Погуглил, оказывается это действительно огромна проблема в Qt. В огромном фреймворке с кучей функций нельзя повернуть label....

Comment: не ясно причём здесь python, pyqt.